# Transform texture for QML Qt3D material

Tags: 3d, qml, qt3d

In my project I have to set some textures for models and configure their orientation. I'm using **Qt 5.15** for now.
I managed to put some texture for `DiffuseSpecularMaterial` setting its `diffuse:` property with `Texture2D { TextureImage { source: "file:res1.png" }}` component.

But I can't find a way to **rotate or scale** this texture.
There is a fine `Texture` component for QtQuick3D, that seems to have needed properties, but I can't move to it and have to stay with Qt3D.Extras, Qt3D.Core, etc...

Here's full code for example (`res1.png` could be any image, just put it in folder):

**.pro** file

```
QT += quick 3dcore 3drender 3dinput 3dquick 3dlogic

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

QML_IMPORT_PATH =

QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

**main.cpp** file

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
  QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  qputenv("QSG_RHI_BACKEND", "opengl");

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
  QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                   &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
    if (!obj && url == objUrl)
      QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
  }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
  engine.load(url);

  return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml** file

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window

import Qt3D.Core
import Qt3D.Render
import Qt3D.Input
import Qt3D.Extras
import QtQuick.Scene3D

Window {
  width: 640
  height: 480
  visible: true
  title: qsTr("Hello World")

  Scene3D
  {
    id: id_Scene3d
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.margins: 10
    focus: true
    aspects: ["input", "logic"]
    cameraAspectRatioMode: Scene3D.AutomaticAspectRatio

    Entity
    {
      id: id_SceneRootEntity

      Camera
      {
        id: id_Camera
        projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
        fieldOfView: 45
        nearPlane : 0.1
        farPlane : 1000.0
        position: Qt.vector3d( -20.0, 20.0, 40.0 )
        upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
        viewCenter: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
      }

      OrbitCameraController
      {
        camera: id_Camera
        lookSpeed: 150
        linearSpeed: 200
      }

      components:
      [
        RenderSettings
        {
          id: id_RenderSettings
          activeFrameGraph:
            ForwardRenderer
            {
              camera: id_Camera
              clearColor: "transparent"
              showDebugOverlay: false
            }
        },
        InputSettings { }
      ]

      Entity
      {
        components:
        [
          PlaneMesh { height: 5; width: 7 }
          ,
          DiffuseSpecularMaterial
          {
            ambient: "white"
            diffuse: Texture2D { TextureImage { source: "file:res1.png" }} // HOW TO ROTATE/SCALE THIS?
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For the scale there is a property on `DiffuseSpecularMaterial`: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt3d-extras-diffusespecularmaterial.html#textureScale-prop. I recall that I once also set the transform matrix for a texture but I have to look it up again.

Comment: Yeah, I found that too. But still rotation is a question. Also setting scale <1.0 leads to ugly textures on the edges. I guess that is something about wrapping mode, but I can't find a way to set it right too.

Comment: QTextureMaterial has this `transform` attribute I found out, but that's of no use for you. Looks like you'd have to implement this yourself. You can reuse the existing material implementation and set an adjusted shader graph on it. Unfortunately, the people from Qt haven't released their node editor so you have to do it manually (or write your own shader graph visualization)